# Restangular doesn't work with lodash

Tags: angularjs, underscore.js, lodash, restangular

I'm starting a project under angular 1.4.5 and i want to use restangular 1.5.1, i load the angular-1.4.5.min.js, lodash-3.10.1.min.js, and **restangular-1.5.1.min.js** files, but when i include `'restangular'` to my module declaration i get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.5/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=Error%3A%20%…ol%2Fsrc%2Fclient%2Fcomponents%2Fangular%2Fangular-1.4.5.min.js%3A19%3A381)
```

Here's where i include the module:

```
(function () {

    'use strict';

    angular.module('app.core', [
        'restangular', 'ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap'
        ]);

})();
```

But when i load underscore instead of lodash it works...

Comment: What about for ui.router? What makes you think the error is with Restangular?

Comment: without restangular, the app works (i mean it renders static pages). @MatthewGreen

Comment: It would help a lot if you actually showed all the files. Try codepen for instance.

Comment: The code you posted works perfectly fine with lodash so the problem is somewhere else. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/epMLav?editors=001

Comment: Hmmm, ok, i'll check out, thanks @Miszy

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this error has anything to do with lodash and restangular.

Generally this error means that angular can not find restangular.js file. Start by checking that the path to restangular.js inside  tag is set right.

Comment: as i said, angular can find restangular when i use underscore, but not when i use lodash...

Comment: This is weird. It could help if you can create a plunker/fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, try to use a newest version of undescore or lodash.

If you see the gitHub RestAngular, you can see the version

https://github.com/mgonto/restangular/blob/master/karma.underscore.conf.js

Right now the newest version is :

restangular = 'v1.6.1';
underscoreVersion = '1.8.3';

This works for me.